# How to make schema less titan graph?How to set schema-default propery?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, schemaless

How to make schema less titan graph?How to set schema-default propery ?
Please suggest a way?Here is my code :

```
try{
//timestamp,1416375283,ipaddress,2097152002,mobilenumber,966566564213,eventname,1000


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/root/edges_sorted.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String csv = "/root/log.CSV";
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csv);
    Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
    conf.setProperty("storage.backend","hbase");
    conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","192.168.51.98");
    conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading","true");
    conf.setProperty("storage.batch-loading",true);
    conf.setProperty("storage.buffer-size",3024000);
    conf.setProperty("storage.tablename",graphName);
    conf.setProperty("ids.block-size", 1000000);
    conf.setProperty("ids.flush ", true);
    //set the db cache
    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache",true);
    //set the cache size
    conf.setProperty("cache.db-cache-size",0.5);
    conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.region-count",3);
    conf.setProperty("storage.hbase.skip-schema-check", false);
    conf.setProperty("storage.index.titan5.backend","elasticsearch");
    conf.setProperty("storage.index.titan5.hostname", "192.168.51.95");
    conf.setProperty("storage.index.titan5.client-only", false);
    conf.setProperty("storage.index.titan5.cluster-name","titancluster");
    conf.setProperty("storage.index.titan5.index-name", indexName);
    conf.setProperty("graph.set-vertex-id",true);

        conf.setProperty("attributes.allow-all",true);
    conf.setProperty("schema.default",false);
    TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(conf);


    titanGraph.makeLabel("reason").manyToMany().make();
    titanGraph.makeLabel("many").manyToMany().make();
    BatchGraph<TitanGraph> titanBatchGraph=new BatchGraph<TitanGraph>(titanGraph,VertexIDType.NUMBER,batchsize);

    titanBatchGraph.setLoadingFromScratch(true);
    String locations[]=CreateDummy1.getCircleList();
    String strLine1="";
    int circleindex=0;
    int count=0;

    Vertex vertex;
    Vertex vertex2;

        count ++;
        if(circleindex==locations.length)
            circleindex=0;



        vertex=titanBatchGraph.getVertex(1);
        if(vertex==null){
             vertex = titanBatchGraph.addVertex(1);
            vertex.setProperty("n",1);
            vertex.setProperty("a",100);
        }

        vertex2=titanBatchGraph.getVertex(2);
        if(vertex2==null){
count++;
vertex2 = titanBatchGraph.addVertex(2);
vertex2.setProperty("n",2);
vertex2.setProperty("a", 10000);
        }

        Edge edge= titanBatchGraph.addEdge(1,vertex,vertex2,"reason");
        edge.setProperty("ti",1);
        edge.setProperty("s", 5);

        //second edge
        vertex=titanBatchGraph.getVertex(1);
        if(vertex==null){
             vertex = titanBatchGraph.addVertex(1);
            vertex.setProperty("n",1);
            vertex.setProperty("a",100);
        }
        else
        {
            vertex.setProperty("n1", 45);
        }

        vertex2=titanBatchGraph.getVertex(2);
        if(vertex2==null){
count++;
vertex2 = titanBatchGraph.addVertex(2);
vertex2.setProperty("n",2);
vertex2.setProperty("a", 10000);
        }

        Edge edge1= titanBatchGraph.addEdge(2,vertex,vertex2,"reason");
        edge1.setProperty("ti",2);
        edge1.setProperty("s",6);
        titanBatchGraph.commit();      
        titanBatchGraph.shutdown();

                }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

How to set scheme-default configuration? how to set it to default so that automatic schemas are generated?Please suggest a way or any alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titan is set in that configuration by default.  To elaborate, this settings `schema.default` is set to `blueprints` automatically.  To force schema definition, you need to set that value to `none`.  The [docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.2/titan-config-ref.html#_schema) read:

> Configures the DefaultSchemaMaker to be used by this graph. If set to
>   none, automatic schema creation is disabled. Defaults to a blueprints
>   compatible schema maker with MULTI edge labels and SINGLE property
>   keys

To enforce a schema you need to do this:

```
conf.setProperty("schema.default","none");
```

and to use the "default" schema creation system you should do:

```
conf.setProperty("schema.default","blueprints");
```

All that said, it is generally a bad idea to allow Titan to create the schema for anything except very simple cases.  If you don't provide Titan a schema, you will lose many optimizations and features that Titan provides and therefore you performance may not be as good as it possible could be.

Comment: In my program I am setting conf.setProperty("schema.default","blueprints"); but still its not working.

Comment: and what are the features I will not be able to use if I use ("schema.default","none")

Comment: You shouldnt need to even set it. It is set to that value by default. Types will be added automatically as you add keys.  If you don't specify a schema you won't get optimizations from vertex centric indices (or any indices for that matter). You should review the docs to learn more.http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.2/schema.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but since i am performing indexing so would I be able to index that new added property by adding key

Comment: Just because you specify `blueprints` for the `schema.default` setting doesn't mean that you can't specify indices and other schema elements.  It just means that if in your code you add a new property key, Titan will auto-type it for you.  If you set to `none` it will throw an exception.

Comment: I am not able to get you can you please give me a example it would really be helpful

Comment: there really is no "example".  all i'm saying is that just because you choose to use `blueprints` as your setting doesn't mean that you can't still create indices and types.  using `blueprints` only means that if a type is not present when you add a new key, Titan will create a default type for you (which will generally be unoptimized).